# { iMacros } How to Loop and Click Next?

Tags: imacros

first time using iMacros.

I want to run a loop 50x then when it is done, click the "Next" button and run the same loop again 50x, click "Next"... until "Next" is no longer clickable.

so far i have this working just 1 time:

```
SET !LOOP 1

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:domain EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:ddmmyy}}.csv

'click NEXT'
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next

WAIT SECONDS=3
```

Comment: the next button is clicked for 50 times in the code you provided, can you give a more detailed explanation of the requirements?

Comment: i need to make a for(loop) i think. 
the requirements are clearly stated above.

Comment: ok so if I loop this in a for loop a new csv file will get created for each record...is that's whats needed?...also can I make an infinite loop with your code and stop the loop when next button is not found?

Comment: 1. no i dont need a new CSV file. i just need one. 
With each TEXT entry added as a new ROW.

2. yes make the loop stop when Next button is not found. thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will help you,

just an explanation to familiarize you with imacros.

1. You need to **create a script.js** file in Imacros and paste this code.
2. do while loop will run the code inside the Braces forever.
3. Then we hardcode the two macros being used as shown below and assign it a javascript variable, inside the loop iimplay() is a javascript function that can run imacros code. so we run **(macroStart)"check next button"** to check if next still exists.
4. The function iimGetLastExtract() will get the last extracted value from the code.
5. If the extracted text is next then break the infinite loop.
6. else run the **"extract and send to csv file" macro (macro2)**.

**Code:**

```
var macro1;
macro1 =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 

var macro2;
macro2 = "CODE:" + "\n"; 
macro2 +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro2 += "TAG XPATH=(/html/body//td[contains(@class,'domain')])[{{j}}] EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro2 += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:/Users/Naren/Desktop/ FILE=output.csv" + "\n"; 


var macro3;
macro3 = "CODE:" + "\n"; 
macro3 +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro3 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next" + "\n"; 
macro3 += "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n"; 

for(var j = 1; j <= 50; j++){
    iimSet("j",j);
    iimPlay(macro2);
}
iimPlay(macro3);
do{
    iimPlay(macro1);
    var macro1Extract = iimGetLastExtract();

    if (macro1Extract !== 'Next') {
         break;
    }
    for(var j = 1; j <= 50; j++){
        iimSet("j",j);
        iimPlay(macro2);
    }
    iimPlay(macro3);
}while (true);
```

Comment: im using the Firefox imacro plugin. It allows me to place JS files in the imacro folder and run them. screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/l/AIHQ9ko3AWtLo5rktNzOYAWPSkIaTYzXVdAB/image.png

is this setup correct? when i run it.. nothing happens.
thanks again!

Comment: @Arturino you need to give play, also are you in the page where you want to run the macro, then one more thing is just try a record and click on the button then open #current.iim it will contain the tag command for the next button, you need to compare it with the tag for next inside the script.js

Comment: yes im on the page. 
Also the tag command for the next button is correct.
however there is no CSV file being outputted.  --- update -- ive also tried using this folder path and  CSV file name: FOLDER=* FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:ddmmyy}}.csv"

Comment: @Arturino have you checked in the FOLDER=C:\ which was set in the code? that is the C drive, try changing this path and check

Comment: im on a Mac. so what worked for me before is using FOLDER=* 
see : http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS

Comment: @lol glad it worked :), so the script is doing what you need right?

Comment: sorry to be clear -  your script didnt work. 

What did work for me before (on other imacro scripts - see below)was the folder directory path i mentioned. 

however when i try using FOLDER=*  or FODER =C:\ ..in your script
>> it produces no CSV files. 

i've even tried simplifying the code to test basic JS external scripts..with this code:

Comment: `var macro2;
macro2 = "CODE:"
macro2 +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+"\n";
macro2 += "SET !LOOP 1"
macro2 += "TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:domain EXTRACT=TXT"
macro2 += "PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}"
macro2 += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:ddmmyy}}.csv"
iimPlay(macro2)
`
and this also doesnt produce any files.

Comment: this code DOES work and produces files ( when run as a macro )
`VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

SET !LOOP 1
TAG POS={{!loop}} TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:domain EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:ddmmyy}}.csv
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next
WAIT SECONDS=2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152190/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-arturino).

Comment: I don't think this solution is available for the free edition anymore. It doesn't allow file access so no way to load the Javascript file